# How add multiple textview at linearlayout in loop

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add some textview to linear layout with a loop but I think I'm just adding one because the text of my text view is not displayed vertically.

```
LinearLayout llPrincipal = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

int contador = 0;
while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
    contador++;
    stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
    TextView tvRutina = new TextView(this);
    tvRutina.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvRutina.setPadding(0, 3, 0, 3);
    tvRutina.setId(contador);
    tvRutina.setText(inputString);

    llPrincipal.addView(tvRutina);
}
```

Xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Answer (score 1):

just add below code in ur while loop :-

```
LinearLayout A = new LinearLayout(this);
A.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICALLY);
llPrincipal .addView(A);
```

or

```
while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
    LinearLayout A = new LinearLayout(this);
A.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICALLY);
contador++;
stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
TextView tvRutina = new TextView(this);
tvRutina.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tvRutina.setPadding(0, 3, 0, 3);
tvRutina.setId(contador);
tvRutina.setText(inputString);

A.addView(tvRutina);
llPrincipal .addView(A);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not work also need to add other linear layout

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout MainLL= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayoutId); 
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
 TextView text = new TextView(this);
 text.setText("The Value of i is :"+i); // <-- does it really compile without the + sign?
 text.setTextSize(12);  
 text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
 text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,          

 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 MainLL.addView(text);
}
```